# floating div 100% width

Tags: css, html, width, repeat, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Foundation framework and I want to make a navigation which takes 100% width of the grid class.

I have 3 divs: `.header_beg`, `.header_rep`, `.header_end`

`.header_beg` is `2px width`, `float: left` and the `.header_end` also

But I want `header_rep` to be 1px width and to `repeat-x` till it fills 100% of the grid class. But it also need it to be `float: left`, but with `float: left` it's not visible. I haven't set width because I want it to be 100% of the grid class.

```
background: red;
height: 49px;
margin-left: 2px;
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WFVER/

I need the green `divs` to be at the beginning and at the end of the red one, and simultaneously the 3 `divs` to be 100% width of the grid class.

Comment: Why do you need a 1px div?

Comment: Because the navigation is rounded

Comment: use border-radius insted

Comment: The navigation:
[link](http://i.imgur.com/icMJp.png?1)

Comment: I'll try it with CSS3... Hope get it work. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with floats but instead of doing it via floats, I will show you how to do this with absolute position:

HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.header .left {
  width: 1px;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
.header .right {
  width: 1px;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
.header .middle {
  width: 998px;
  background: url(images.png) repeat-x;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  height: 20px;
}
```